# Add 4000 records to combobox in devexpress grid view causes an error

Tags: c#, combobox, devexpress

I have a `devexpress gridview` .that has `combobox`as you can see here:

[image]

In my form load i load my data for these `combobox` as you can see :

```
   private void frmWeld_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RefreshDropDownlist();

        }
public void RefreshDropDownlist()
        {
            lstJoint.Items.Clear();
            lstline.Items.Clear();
            ControllerList.Items.Clear();
            List<string> lstJointList = _jointRepository.Get().Select(i => i.JointNumber).ToList();
            foreach (string joint in lstJointList)
            {
                lstJoint.Items.Add(joint);
            }
            List<string> lstLines = _lineRepository.Get().Select(i => i.LineNumber).ToList();
            foreach (string line in lstLines)
            {
                lstline.Items.Add(line);
            }
}
```

Each list have 4000 records to add to combobox so my application works very slow in fist time that i open the form .is there any solution like data source that i can use it ?

Comment: Wrong design idea to put 4000 items in a combobox. Do you really expects your user to browse this list to find the item they need? I would put a link label or a button that opens a search form.

Comment: yes you are right.but in fact i have lots of data and i have to load it in combo box ,because my design should be like excel column.

Comment: Still not a good idea. If you have many datas record you need to structure&filter them, not dump the whole stuff onto the user.. So: No, this cannot ever be made 'usable'.

Comment: Have you tried using a databound control instead, such as a RepositoryItemLookUpEdit?

Comment: Steve and TaW are right.  I think if I saw a drop-down with 4000 items in it, I would uninstall that software immediately.